# Adapter for external web service into existing one

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, integration, adapter

I am totally new to web services.

I have developed a web service to search in RDF files on a server and display URIs.

Now I would like to use an adapter for invoking an external web service (catalogue of life), but I have no idea where to start from.

http://www.catalogueoflife.org/col/webservice

Are there any tutorials around to show how to do it?

I am using JavaEE with Jersey and developing a REST web service.